# Evaluating surds - different answers using different methods?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, binomial-theorem

I am given that $$ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{5}} \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{8\sqrt{2}} + \frac{3}{128\sqrt{2}} - \frac{5}{1024\sqrt{2}}$$

and asked to show $$ \sqrt{5} \approx \frac{2048}{915}$$.

Evaluating the above in two different ways seems to give slightly different answers, even though there doesn't seem to be any reason it should.

Method 1:
$$ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{5}} \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{8\sqrt{2}} + \frac{3}{128\sqrt{2}} - \frac{5}{1024\sqrt{2}}$$
$$ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{5}} \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1 - \frac{1}{8} + \frac{3}{128} - \frac{5}{1024})$$
$$ {\sqrt{2}} \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1 - \frac{1}{8} + \frac{3}{128} - \frac{5}{1024}){\sqrt{5}}$$
$$2 \approx  (1 - \frac{1}{8} + \frac{3}{128} - \frac{5}{1024}){\sqrt{5}}$$
$$2 \approx  (\frac{915}{1024}){\sqrt{5}}$$
$${\sqrt{5}} \approx  \frac{2048}{915}$$

Note: $$\frac{2048}{915} = 2.238251366$$

Method 2: 
$$ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{5}} \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{8\sqrt{2}} + \frac{3}{128\sqrt{2}} - \frac{5}{1024\sqrt{2}}$$
$$ \frac{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{5}\sqrt{5}} \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{8\sqrt{2}} + \frac{3}{128\sqrt{2}} - \frac{5}{1024\sqrt{2}}$$
$$ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{{5}}\sqrt{5} \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{8\sqrt{2}} + \frac{3}{128\sqrt{2}} - \frac{5}{1024\sqrt{2}}$$
$$\sqrt{5} \approx (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{8\sqrt{2}} + \frac{3}{128\sqrt{2}} - \frac{5}{1024\sqrt{2}})\frac{5}{\sqrt{2}}$$
$$\sqrt{5} \approx (\frac{5}{{2}} - \frac{5}{8(2)} + \frac{15}{128(2)} - \frac{25}{1024(2)})$$
$$\sqrt{5} \approx \frac{4575}{{2048}}$$

Note: $$\frac{4575}{2048} = 2.233886719$$

The two methods give different but awfully close answers. Nevertheless, the question asks for an exact term so giving the second answer would be wrong. Am I missing something that is causing a loss of precision in Method 2?

Comment: Okay sure, but what is in Method 2 that led to this closer approximation? There doesn't seem to be such difference! Method 1 is just factorising first, Method 2 proceeds with expanded form then rationalising. @PiyushDivyanakar

Comment: Actually the surd of 5 gives 2.236067977 on my calculator, so Method 1 is closer approx actually. @PiyushDivyanakar

Answer (score 5):

I would explain like this:

When we say $a \approx b$ $(a,b,n\in\mathbb{R})$, this does not necessary mean that $na\approx nb$.

This is because $na-nb=n(a-b)$, this difference can increase dramatically if $|n|$ increases. When both sides of the approximation is multiplied by $n$ times, their difference is also increased by $n$ times.

The second and third steps of method $1$ looks like this:

> $$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{5}} \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1 - \frac{1}{8} + \frac{3}{128} - \frac{5}{1024})$$
>
> $${\sqrt{2}} \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1 - \frac{1}{8} + \frac{3}{128} - \frac{5}{1024}){\sqrt{5}}$$

The second line is always true because

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{8\sqrt{2}} + \frac{3}{128\sqrt{2}} - \frac{5}{1024\sqrt{2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(1 - \frac{1}{8} + \frac{3}{128} - \frac{5}{1024}\right)$$

However, the third line is not always true, as the difference between the left hand side and the right hand side is increased by $\sqrt{5}$ times (obviously, both sides are positive).

The fourth step also increases the difference between both sides:

> $$2 \approx  (1 - \frac{1}{8} + \frac{3}{128} - \frac{5}{1024}){\sqrt{5}}$$

This time the difference between both sides is increased again by $\sqrt{2}$ times, which makes the difference from the beginning increased by $\sqrt{5}\times \sqrt{2}=\sqrt{10}$ times overall.

The fifth step in method $1$ looks like this:

> $$2 \approx  (\frac{915}{1024}){\sqrt{5}}$$

The fifth step is true because the value of the right hand side is not changed.

The sixth step is method $1$ looks like this:

> $${\sqrt{5}} \approx  \frac{2048}{915}$$

There are two ways to make a conclusion from the fifth step:

- Method $1$ divides both sides by $\dfrac{915}{1024}$, or multiplies both sides by $\dfrac{1024}{915}$, this makes the difference between both sides increased again by $\dfrac{1024}{915}$ times. Because of this, the "beginning" difference has been increased by $\dfrac{1024}{915}\sqrt{10}$ times overall.
- Another method: From the fifth step, multiply both sides by $\dfrac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$ times. This makes the difference increase again by $\dfrac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$ times and the final result is indeed $\sqrt{5} \approx \dfrac{4575}{{2048}}$, this is the answer from method $2$. Doing it this way, the "beginning" difference has been increased by $\sqrt{10}\times\dfrac{\sqrt{5}}{2}=\dfrac{5\sqrt{2}}{2}$ times.

For method $2$, I will do this quickly:

> $$ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{5}} \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{8\sqrt{2}} + \frac{3}{128\sqrt{2}} - \frac{5}{1024\sqrt{2}}$$
> $$ \frac{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{5}\sqrt{5}} \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{8\sqrt{2}} + \frac{3}{128\sqrt{2}} - \frac{5}{1024\sqrt{2}}$$
> $$ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{{5}}\sqrt{5} \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{8\sqrt{2}} + \frac{3}{128\sqrt{2}} - \frac{5}{1024\sqrt{2}}$$

All three steps do not increase the difference between both sides.

> $$\sqrt{5} \approx (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{8\sqrt{2}} + \frac{3}{128\sqrt{2}} - \frac{5}{1024\sqrt{2}})\frac{5}{\sqrt{2}}$$

The difference between both sides is increased by $\dfrac{5}{\sqrt{2}}=\dfrac{5\sqrt{2}}{2}$ times.

> $$\sqrt{5} \approx (\frac{5}{{2}} - \frac{5}{8(2)} + \frac{15}{128(2)} - \frac{25}{1024(2)})$$
> $$\sqrt{5} \approx \frac{4575}{{2048}}$$

The difference between both sides is not changed in either of the steps above, so the overall differenced is increased by $\dfrac{5\sqrt{2}}{2}$ times, which is the same as the second method of the last step of method $1$.

Using a calculator:

> $\dfrac{1024}{915}\sqrt{10}=3.538986146...$
>
> $\dfrac{5\sqrt{2}}{2}=3.535533906...$

Two values are very close to each other, thus explain why the difference is so small.

**Note:** I did not say anything about the correctness of either of these two methods, this is just a proof about why two methods are different.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$ 2048/915 = \frac 5{4575/2048} $$

The mapping $x\mapsto 5/x $ would not change the actual $\sqrt 5$, but it turns your two approximations into each other.

If you assume (counterfactually) that one of the approximations actually equals $\sqrt 5$, you can "prove" that it equals the other.

One is not really more precise than the other -- in fact the the *logarithmic* distance between each of them and the exact $\sqrt 5$ is the same, just on opposite sides.

Answer (score 1):

I'm putting this here just because I didn't see anyone mention it.

\begin{align}
   \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{5}} 
   &\approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} 
          - \frac{1}{8\sqrt{2}} 
          + \frac{3}{128\sqrt{2}} 
          - \frac{5}{1024\sqrt{2}} \\
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} 
   &\approx \frac{1}{2} 
          - \frac{1}{16} 
          + \frac{3}{256} 
          - \frac{5}{2048} \\
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} 
   &\approx \frac{915}{2048} \\
   \sqrt 5 &\approx \dfrac{2048}{915}
\end{align}

If you think of $x \approx y$ to mean that $x = y + \epsilon$ for some "small" value of $\epsilon$, then it should not come as a suprise to find that $f(x) \ne f(y) + \epsilon$ or even that $f(x) \ne f(y) + f(\epsilon)$.

method 1

\begin{align} 
  \frac{\sqrt 2}{\sqrt 5} 
     &= \frac{1}
     {\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{8\sqrt{2}}+\frac{3}{128\sqrt{2}}
     -\frac{5}{1024\sqrt{2}} + \epsilon \\
  \frac{\sqrt 2}{\sqrt 5} 
     &= \frac{1}
     {\sqrt 2}(1 - \frac{1}{8} + \frac{3}{128} - \frac{5}{1024})
     + \epsilon\\
  {\sqrt 2} - \sqrt 5 \epsilon
     &\approx \frac{1}
     {\sqrt{2}}(1 - \frac{1}{8} + \frac{3}{128} - \frac{5}{1024}){\sqrt 5} \\
  2 - \sqrt{10}\epsilon 
     &=  (1 - \frac{1}{8} + \frac{3}{128} - \frac{5}{1024}){\sqrt 5} \\
  2 - \sqrt{10}\epsilon &=  (\frac{915}{1024}){\sqrt 5} \\
  {\sqrt 5} &=  \frac{2048}{915} - \frac{1024}{915}\sqrt{10}\epsilon
\end{align}

method 2

\begin{align} 
   \frac{\sqrt 2}{\sqrt 5} 
      &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{8\sqrt 2} + \frac{3}{128\sqrt 2} 
      - \frac{5}{1024\sqrt 2} + \epsilon \\
   \frac{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{5}\sqrt{5}} 
      &= \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} - \frac{1}{8\sqrt 2} + \frac{3}{128\sqrt 2} 
      - \frac{5}{1024\sqrt 2} + \epsilon \\
   \frac{\sqrt 2}{5} \sqrt{5} 
      &= \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} - \frac{1}{8\sqrt 2} + \frac{3}{128\sqrt 2} 
      - \frac{5}{1024\sqrt 2} + \epsilon \\
   \sqrt 5 
      &= \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} - \frac{1}{8\sqrt 2} + \frac{3}{128\sqrt 2} - 
      \frac{5}{1024\sqrt 2} \right)\frac{5}{\sqrt 2}  
      + \frac{5}{\sqrt 2}\epsilon \\
   \sqrt{5} 
      &= \frac 52 - \frac{5}{8(2)} + \frac{15}{128(2)} - \frac{25}{1024(2)}
      + \frac{5}{\sqrt 2}\epsilon \\
   \sqrt{5} 
      &= \frac{4575}{2048}
      + \frac{5}{\sqrt 2}\epsilon \\
\end{align}

The errors are clearly different.